# How to get color from buttons?

Tags: android

I need to find the red buttons on Activity and set orange background color to these buttons.

When I click on the button I set it to red:

`view.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));`

When I click on another button, the red buttons should turn orange.

```
public void Active(View view){
    for (View but : buttons) {
        but.setClickable(true);
            but.setBackgroundTintList();
    }
}
```

I do not know how to get the id of the colors

Comment: It is very bad practise

Comment: What is buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me is unclear your question but I'll try to answer it.

Supposing buttons is a `List<Button>`, so what you can do is.

```
for(View but : buttons){
  int color = ((ColorDrawable)but.getBackground()).getColor();
  if(color == Color.Red){
    //This button is red change it to orange
    but.setBackgroundColor(R.colors.orange);
  }
}
```

And when you are clicking the button use

```
button.setBackgroundResource(Color.Red);
```

Comment: Android studio don't have (R.colors.orange) color i used rgb

Comment: Yap, you can also define your color in your `colors.xml` folder :)

Answer (score 0):

```
but.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

use that